# Zend_Form - Array based elements?

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-form

Using Zend_Form, how would I create form elements like this:

```
<input type="text" name="element[1]" value="" />
<input type="text" name="element[2]" value="" />
// etc...
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can either use subforms:

```
$form = new Zend_Form();

$subForm = new Zend_Form_SubForm();
$subForm->addElement('Text', '1')
        ->addElement('Text', '2');

$form->addSubForm($subForm, 'element');
```

Or you should also be able to use `setBelongsTo()` on the form elements (untested):

```
$form = new Zend_Form();
$form->addElement('Text', '1', array('belongsTo' => 'element'))
     ->addElement('Text', '2', array('belongsTo' => 'element'));
```

Comment: Second, form seems to be more clean and straight-forward, and works ok (tested).

Comment: If anyone has issues with validation, getValue() etc - see this *resolved* ticket on ZF tracker: http://framework.zend.com/issues/browse/ZF-2563

Comment: I'd go with sub-forms, belongsTo caused me all sorts of grief, because I wanted to use repeating sets of composite fields (example: street and postal address fields which I want to share identically named sub-fields). Only use belongsTo for the most basic of field grouping, otherwise go with subforms and save yourself the hassle.

Answer (score 2):

I contend that `setBelongsTo` is of substandard quality, as one is unable to set default values. And so, at the present time, there's no reasonable way to achieve your objective.