# how to add zend form elements to the form in php?

Tags: php, zend-framework, foreach, zend-form

i have a foreach loop in my zend form, in this case the `$this->args[1]`has a count of 5 :

```
foreach ($this->args[1] as $val)
    {

        $submitImage = new Zend_Form_Element_Image('submit_image');
        $checkBox = new Zend_Form_Element_Checkbox('id_checkbox');

        $this->addElement( $submitImage ->setImage($val->full_path) );
        $this->addElement( $checkBox ->setValue($val->id) );
    }
```

the problem i encounter is that the `$submitImage` and `$checkBox` get overwritten and i only get one element of each, the last one.

any ideas how to make them all show up?

thanks

i've also tried:

```
$i=0;
foreach ($this->args[1] as $val)
    {

        $submitImage = 'submitImage'.$i;
            $checkBox = 'checkBox'.$i;

        $submitImage = new Zend_Form_Element_Image('submit_image');
        $checkBox = new Zend_Form_Element_Checkbox('id_checkbox');

        $this->addElement( $submitImage ->setImage($val->full_path) );
        $this->addElement( $checkBox ->setValue($val->id) );
    $i++;
    }
```

but it doesn't work

Comment: You will have to give each element a unique name, or use subforms.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/405897/zend-form-array-based-elements

Answer (score 4, accepted):

your really close, only need minor fixes. Anything to make the name of the element unique.

```
foreach ($this->args[1] as $val)
    {

        $submitImage = new Zend_Form_Element_Image('submit_image'. $val->id);
        $checkBox = new Zend_Form_Element_Checkbox('id_checkbox' . $val->id);

        $this->addElement( $submitImage ->setImage($val->full_path) );
        $this->addElement( $checkBox ->setValue($val->id) );
    }
```

or if you like

```
$i=0;
foreach ($this->args[1] as $val)
    {

        $image = 'submitImage'.$i;
            $box = 'checkBox'.$i;

        $submitImage = new Zend_Form_Element_Image($image);
        $checkBox = new Zend_Form_Element_Checkbox($box);

        $this->addElement( $submitImage ->setImage($val->full_path) );
        $this->addElement( $checkBox ->setValue($val->id) );
    $i++;
    }
```

Liyali has the right of it I'm just more verbose :)

**[EDIT]**
corrected variable collision in second loop.

Comment: the first foreach worked. the second one didn't for some reason, just in case someone else reads this answer. Lots of thanks

Answer (score 2):

Your element names must be **different**.

```
 $submitImage = new Zend_Form_Element_Image($submitImage);
 $checkBox = new Zend_Form_Element_Checkbox($checkBox);
```